# How can I use Xpath to find frequency of pairs of attribute values?

Tags: xpath, attributes

I'm editing a Latin text in xml. It appears in multiple manuscripts and printings, and I'm tracking the textual variations between them. I want to use Xpath to count how often certain pairs of witnesses share the same variants. W, S, J, R, C, I, and O are the different witnesses.

For example:

````
    ```<app>
           <rdg wit="#W #S #J">Brecknock</rdg>
           <rdg wit="#R">Brechnok</rdg>
           <rdg wit="#C #I #O">Brechnock</rdg>
     </app>```
````

For another:

````
```<app>
           <rdg wit="#W #R #I #C #O">nostris</rdg>
           <rdg wit="#S #J">nostra</rdg>
        </app>```
````

I can easily isolate each witness list that includes, say, R:

````
```//rdg[contains(@wit, "R")]```
````

But how can I isolate each @wit list that includes, say, both R *and* W, or any other pair?

The goal will be to plug this into an XSLT to output an SVG that graphs the mathematical relationship (frequency of agreement) between each pair of witnesses. But one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I finally figured it out, so I'll share it here in case anyone else is a dumb as I am:

```
'''//rdg[contains(@wit, "R") and contains(@wit, "W")]'''
```

I was trying to include the "and" under a single "contains".